# Cartthrob entity_id on add to cart. "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'"

Tags: cartthrob

We have inherited a site which uses Cartthrob on Expression Engine. The site on the live environment works fine but on the Development environment it throws the below error.

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT `exp_channel_titles`.*, `exp_channel_data`.*, `exp_channels`.* FROM (`exp_channel_titles`) JOIN `exp_channel_data` ON `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` = `exp_channel_data`.`entry_id` JOIN `exp_channels` ON `exp_channels`.`channel_id` = `exp_channel_titles`.`channel_id` WHERE `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` IN (Array)

Filename: third_party/cartthrob/models/cartthrob_entries_model.php

Line Number: 183

I've had a look and it seems that a multi-demensional array is getting passed into the where_in clause and that is confusing it. But what is confusing me is why this is happening. I am reluctant to go messing with the Core code and I don't understand it enough to easily fix the problem. So I was wondering if anyone could help me or had seen this problem themselves?

Used to using Wordpress and Magento so this is a complete new area for me.

EE Version v2.7.2
CartThrob Version 2.4

Hope you can help!

Thanks,
Stu

Comment: It would be nice if you could tell us where you are seeing this error. Is it in the control pannel or is on a particular template.

Comment: It's on the template. You use the site as normal, you go through the 'Gifts' section and then go to buy the 'Gift' the page redirects and then the error is shown